# Need to pull out Json Data (nested array) from a single column dataframe - Table is coming out as Null with schema read -Scala

Tags: json, scala, multidimensional-array, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to pull out data as below from data frame. The Json data which has nested arrays is completely in one column(_c1). I want to pull it out and create it as separate data frame with valid column names. One sample record would be as below.

```
|_c1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"Id":"31279605299","Type":"12121212","client":"Checklist _API","eventTime":"2020-03-17T15:50:30.640Z","eventType":"Event","payload":{"sourceApp":"ios","questionnaire":{"version":"1.0","question":"How to resolve ? ","fb":"Na"}}}
```

I am reading it to a schema as,

```
val schema=StructType(Array(
      StructField("Id", StringType, false),
      StructField("Type", StringType, false),
      StructField("client", StringType, false),
      StructField("eventTime", StringType, false),
      StructField("eventType", StringType, false),
      StructField("payload", ArrayType(StructType(Array(
        StructField("sourceApp", StringType, false),
        StructField("questionnaire", ArrayType(StructType(Array(
          StructField("version", StringType, false),
          StructField("question", StringType, false),
          StructField("fb", StringType, false)))))
      ))))
    ))

      val json_paral = DF.select(from_json(col("_c1"),schema))
`
Structure comes out as below,
`

 |-- jsontostructs(_c1): struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- client: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- eventTime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- eventType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- payload: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- sourceApp: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- questionnaire: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- version: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- question: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- fb: string (nullable = true)
```

The structure is good but when I check the dataframe all data is coming out as NULL. Is the read fine ? Not getting any parsing issues either.

Comment: Hi can you check my answer. Please upvote + accept if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of reading it to schema I tried making it to a value as

```
val Df = json_DF.map(r => r.getString(0))
```

This will pull the data as a string on which the below would pull it out with the keys as column names.

```
val g1DF=spark.read.json(Df)
```

Did some lateral view explode nested to pull out nested array values.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this helps-

### 1. Load the data

```
val data = """{"Id":"31279605299","Type":"12121212","client":"Checklist _API","eventTime":"2020-03-17T15:50:30.640Z","eventType":"Event","payload":{"sourceApp":"ios","questionnaire":{"version":"1.0","question":"How to resolve ? ","fb":"Na"}}} """

    val df = Seq(data).toDF("jsonCol")
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()
```

Output-

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|jsonCol                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"Id":"31279605299","Type":"12121212","client":"Checklist _API","eventTime":"2020-03-17T15:50:30.640Z","eventType":"Event","payload":{"sourceApp":"ios","questionnaire":{"version":"1.0","question":"How to resolve ? ","fb":"Na"}}} |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

root
 |-- jsonCol: string (nullable = true)
```

### 2. extract the json string to separate fileds

```
 df.select(json_tuple(col("jsonCol"), "Id", "Type", "client", "eventTime", "eventType", "payload"))
      .show(false)
```

Output-

```
+-----------+--------+--------------+------------------------+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|c0         |c1      |c2            |c3                      |c4   |c5                                                                                            |
+-----------+--------+--------------+------------------------+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|31279605299|12121212|Checklist _API|2020-03-17T15:50:30.640Z|Event|{"sourceApp":"ios","questionnaire":{"version":"1.0","question":"How to resolve ? ","fb":"Na"}}|
+-----------+--------+--------------+------------------------+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

### 3. using `from_json(..)`

```scala
val processed = df.select(
      expr("from_json(jsonCol, 'struct<Id:string,Type:string,client:string,eventTime:string, eventType:string," +
      "payload:struct<questionnaire:struct<fb:string,question:string,version:string>,sourceApp:string>>')")
        .as("json_converted"))
      processed.show(false)
      processed.printSchema()
```

Output-

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|json_converted                                                                                               |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[31279605299, 12121212, Checklist _API, 2020-03-17T15:50:30.640Z, Event, [[Na, How to resolve ? , 1.0], ios]]|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

root
 |-- json_converted: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- client: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- eventTime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- eventType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- payload: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- questionnaire: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- fb: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- question: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- version: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sourceApp: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thanks. This won't save my purpose as I am getting the data as dataframe. I need the data frame to be pulled out to a json format. Please see the answer below.